# Do I need to sand before recoating a worn polyurethane finish?

Tags: polyurethane

I polyurethaned a tabletop and some spots have worn off. What is my best option to fix this? Do I have to sand the whole top and re-apply?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to sand to the degree that you're satisfied with the smoothness of the surface. If you have scratches or chips, deal with them. Then apply urethane in multiple thin coats, allowing appropriate dry time between and optionally buff with steel wool, until you're satisfied with the finish.

Answer (score 0):

Sand down any chips, scratches, and nicks, then give the entire top a fine sanding and thorough wipe down with a tack cloth. This will help the new finish bond well by ensuring removal of anything that might interfere (grease, oil, dirt, etc.) and also will help ensure uniformity of finish.

Do **not** use steel wool if you intend to use a waterborne finish, and I do recommend water-based varnish; it dries quick and gives a nice hard gloss finish. Use top quality brushes please, you will be much happier with the results.

Comment: Water-based is the word for coatings based in water, i.e. almost everything at the hardware store these days.  Water*borne* is the word for coatings with a VOC chemical base, which are being forced into emulsion with water to thin it enough to spray, the point being to reduce VOCs.  These are very complex to use and are used in production environments such as factories where their idiosyncrasies can be managed.

Comment: @Harper, all due respect but the term is not so specific and both are often used interchangeably in the consumer finish market. I used the term "waterborne" deliberately, because one of the top (and one of the oldest) American consumer finishes manufacturers brands their consumer grade water-based varnish as "waterborne". And it is a great product. http://www.cabotstain.com/pdf/WB_Poly.pdf

Comment: My optical mouse stops recognizing my urethaned oak tabletop every couple years. A 320 grit sanding fixes that. If I wanted to revarnish the entire top, I'd take it to no higher than 250 grit so as to ensure good adhesion between old and new layers.